# Substituir tag HTML por texto com regex

Tags: java, regex

Preciso substituir uma tag HTML (com um atributo especifico) por um texto, segue o meu exemplo a seguir:

```
String stringTest = '<variable data-id="1" name="test2" style="background-color:red;">Variable test</variable> isto é texto <variable style="background-color:red;" name="test" data-id="2">Variable Test2</variable> outro texto';

String value = "myText";

String pattern = "<variable\\s.*?name=['\"]test['\"]?.*?[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/variable>";
String newString = stringTest.replaceAll(pattern , value);
```

A ideia é substituir a tag `variable` que contém o atributo `name="test"` pelo texto `"myText"`.

Acontece que ambas as tags estão a ser substituidas. Neste caso a tag com o `name="test2"` não quero que seja substituída.

O resultado que obtenho com o código acima é:

```
"myText isto é texto myText outro texto"
```

Comment: [Desculpa não resisti :D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6087092)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é mudar a regex para:

```
String stringTest = "<variable data-id=\"1\" name=\"test2\" style=\"background-color:red;\">Variable test</variable> isto é texto <variable style=\"background-color:red;\" name=\"test\" data-id=\"2\">Variable Test2</variable> outro texto";
String value = "myText";
String pattern = "<variable\\s[^>]*?name=['\"]test['\"].*?[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/variable>";
String newString = stringTest.replaceAll(pattern, value);
System.out.println(newString);
```

Eu removi o `?` logo depois do segundo `['\"]`, pois isso tornava as aspas opcionais, e com isso o ponto que vem logo em seguida poderia acabar pegando "test2".

Também coloquei `[^>]` logo depois de `variable\\s`, pois assim eu garanto que a regex não sairá da tag - usando o ponto, ela acabava saindo da primeira tag e "invadindo" a segunda ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/R2PkM4/1/)) - o `.*?` só garante que a regex pegará o mínimo necessário para satisfazê-la, e o mínimo necessário nesse caso era ir até a segunda tag. Já usando `[^>]`, eu garanto que a regex vai no máximo até o próximo `>`, não correndo o risco de "invadir" outras tags ([veja a diferença](https://regex101.com/r/R2PkM4/2/)).

Com a regex acima, somente a segunda tag é substituída, e o resultado é:

```
<variable data-id="1" name="test2" style="background-color:red;">Variable test</variable> isto é texto myText outro texto
```

---

Se quiser, também pode usar:

```
String pattern = "<variable\\s[^>]*?name=['\"]test['\"].*?[^>]*>[^<]*<\\/variable>";
```

Dentro das tags eu uso `[^<]*` (zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam `<`). Isso é válido caso a tag `variable` não tenha outras tags dentro dela, assim a regex vai pegando tudo até encontrar um `<`.

---

Vale lembrar também que as duas opções acima não funcionam caso você tenha uma tag `variable` dentro de outra ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/R2PkM4/3/)). Neste caso, é melhor usar algum *parser* de XML/HTML.

Comment: Top, muito obrigado!!!